# How to import uuid v4 in TypeScript React.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use uuid as a random unique id generator. But I can't import uuid v4. there showing red underline "Could not find a declaration file for module 'uuid' ".    and when I declare the path of file the red underline comes on 'v4' and shows me "node_modules/uuid/package"' has no exported member 'v4''

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

export const products = [
  {
    id: uuid(),
    title: 'iPhone 11',
    category: 'electric',
  },

];
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure also to install the type definitions for uuid:

```
npm install --save @types/uuid
```